# Using command r.out.ascii in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, import, ascii

I have raster in .bil format which I want to save in GRASS GIS with r.out.ascii. I get this result in .txt file:

```
north: 1N
south: 0
east: 1E
west: 0
rows: 1
cols: 1
55537
```

I suppose it is something wrong, because of dimensions of this .txt file. I didn't change any options in r.out.ascii window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to import the file to a Grass GIS dataset then after that you can export to the format you wish.

Also you can easily convert "GUIless" way, it using GDAL with this command on your shell

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid yourfile.bil outputfile.asc
```

This is for Arc/Info type more options here [Gdal Raster formasts](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html)

Or try [Saga GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/) if none of the above work...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You write "I have raster in .bil format" - fine, but you also need to have the related metadata. Then you write "which I want to save in GRASS GIS with r.out.ascii." If you want to import the map **into** GRASS GIS, then it is r.in.bin.

If you want to export a raster map from GRASS to BIL, then use r.out.bin or r.out.gdal. If to ASCII format, then r.out.ascii.